# PHP: Open website in php

Tags: php, web

I need to open a fully working website in a php-file. The user doesn't have internet access but the server does. I'm currently using "file_get_contents" but that doesn't work for every website (for example facebook). It works for google, but non ascii characters can't be displayed as well as pictures.

How can I achieve this so that the displayed website (any url) is working?

This is the error for facebook:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/load.php on line 8 Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.facebook.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/load.php on line 8

Comment: I dont know if I understand well what you want but maybe CURL library may help you

Comment: Where this does not work, perhaps you need to receive and send cookies to the remote site.

Comment: It looks like someone's trying to bypass company's security policy...

Comment: @DavidJashi No I'm not trying to bypass the security policy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is write a web proxy.

Try using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/) script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS issue because of the line

```
 Name or service not known in /home/load.php
```

Can you ping facebook from the Server?

Try using fixed IP for now.